# undefined is not an object ( 'evaluating props.user.map') React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello for some reason when I try to map through a state that I am passing through from another component I get this error undefined is not an object ( 'evaluating props.user.map') and I have no idea why.

Here is where I am getting the state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";

export class FakeInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: [
        {
          image: "Food",
          name: "Thomas King",
          Age: "23",
          description: "I am looking to meet new people",
          location: "South Carolina",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {this.state.user.map((item) => (
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default FakeInfo;
```

Here is where I am mapping through the state and where I am getting the error:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import FakeInfo from "../UserPage/FakeProfileInfo";

const ViewProfile = (props) => (
  <View>
    {props.user.map((item) => (
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);

export default ViewProfile;
```

Comment: mh try to use: {this.state.user[0].map((item) => ( ..... do you get a result?

Comment: Got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use "ViewProfile" in "FakeInfo" and vice versa. try this:

ViewProfile

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";

const ViewProfile = (props) => (
  <View>
       <Text>{props.user.name}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default ViewProfile;
```

FakeInfo

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import ViewProfile from '{ViewProfilePath}';

export class FakeInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: [
        {
          image: "Food",
          name: "Thomas King",
          Age: "23",
          description: "I am looking to meet new people",
          location: "South Carolina",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {this.state.user.map((item, key) => <ViewProfile user={item} key={key} />)}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default FakeInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really send 'user' in `ViewProfile` props?

I'll recommend you to write like this if you use ES6:

```js
const ViewProfile = ({user = []}) => (
  <View>
    {props.user.map((item) => (
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

or

```js
const ViewProfile = (props) => (
  <View>
    {props.user && props.user.map((item) => (
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

Use it:

```
const ViewProfile = (props) => (
  <View>
    {props.user && props.user.map((item) => (
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);

const Page = (props) => (
  <View>
    <ViewProfile user={[{
          name: "Thomas King",
          Age: "23",
        }]} />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Since I imported FakeInfo that should mean I have access to that file's state... At leasts that how it works in normal React. I just started learning react native.

Comment: it's shouldn't mean that. You've just import some file in some variable.

Comment: Every React Component have own state. Read about redux and global states.

Comment: @samantha *Since I imported FakeInfo that should mean I have access to that file's state* - that's not how it works in react or react-native. Something or someone has misled you

Comment: @luther For some reason when I use your solution I don't get the error but the text doesn't render..

Comment: You won't get an error because `user` now has a default value of an empty array. So `map` is allowed to be called. But you have not passed `user` as a prop, so it will always be an empty array. You have to pass it explicitly.

Comment: Ahhh you are absolutely right, I forgot I can't just import it! Thank you so much for the reminder!